# Rest Api Return

Tags: rest

I'm building a rest api and was wondering about returning errors. Currently, my plan was to use the http status codes but also always return a result. The result would look like the following, if an error occured or not.

```
{
"Data":[the data],"
Errors":[the errors]
}
```

Basically, if an error occurred a Http Status code of 4xx or 5xx would be returned and the Errors collection in the returned JSON would have more details about the error, with the Data section being null. If the call succeeded a Http Status code of 200 would be returned with the data element containing the requested data, and the errors element would be empty.

Would this be a good way of returning data with error information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my design, I didn't include both the 'data' and the 'errors' properties in the response JSON object.

If the API succeeds, I will return the 'data' only. And the http status code is 2XXX.

If the API fails, I will return a 'error' object. The http status follows the specification defined in section 10 of RFC 2616.

An example of my error object is as below.

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 100
Date: Thu, 08 Nov 2012 07:07:05 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "type": "error",
  "status": 404,
  "message": "Not Found",
  "help_url": "/api/help.html"
}
```

Comment: You should update your reference of RFC 2616 to point towards RFC 7231 (or one of its companion RFCs 7230-7235) as Mark Nottingham, one of the engineers behind HTTP, stated that [RFC 2616 is dead](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead)

Answer (score 0):

I am also using this approach. I understand this doesn't follow standard convention. But whatever. I think it can be argued either way. For me personally, my API's are not publicly available (they are all used internally by my application). So i think it's one of those "it depends" kind of situation.

All of my API's return the same data structure with a T template payload. The data structure itself is nice because the consumer has everything they need (success status, error codes, error details, and of course the data payload itself).

This way my presentation layer can treat all http responses uniformly in a friendly way.

Comment: The problem here is, that you mingle meta-data with actual content which may distract clients from their actual task. For internal stuff REST (in its true meaning) isn't needed as one is usually in control of both, client and server. For APIs that have a lot of clients, especially ones not under your control, things look different. [RFC 7807](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7807) specifies an own error message format in the name of `application/problem+json` (or xml) which standardizes the way error details may be returned to the client, if HTTP status codes are not sufficient enough

Comment: @RomanVottner - Thanks. Now i am really considering undoing what i thought was a great idea. Now I should be able to type cast the response into a class contract right?

Comment: I guess i can check my API responses using something like Postman and play around with the raw responses.

Comment: One of the most common failures in REST is that resources are considered to return types, which is [not the case](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html)! Clients and server should use content-type negotiation to agree on a representation format both understand and support. Everything else requires out-of-band information (in external documentation or what not) and may lead to interoperability issues later on, either due to customizations or extensions or due to a lack of general support of that syntax.